# sql query string as number vs string in int columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data that is either a string or number, but I don't know in advance.

Now I have two options:

1.

```
id, key, data_string[varchar]
1, gender, m
1, age, 25
2, gender, f
2, age, 54
2, country, USA

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE key = 'age' AND data_string > 20
```

2.

```
id, key, data_string[varchar], data_number[decimal]
1, gender, m, null
1, age, null, 25
2, gender, f, null
2, age, null, 54
2, country, USA, null

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE key = 'age' AND (data_string > 25 OR data_number > 25)
```

I am wondering if the OR with nulls is going to be fast than having comparisons with int and strings

Comment: Simplest would probably be to convert your data to sane types and/or not use a sql rdbms as a key-value store. As to the performance, you could just try these and time them.

Comment: While you don't know in general whether it's a string or number, when you're testing for `age` don't you know that it will be a number? So there will never be anything in `data_string` in those rows.

Comment: In general, `OR` is a performance-killer in MySQL. If the `data_XXX` columns are indexed, it probably won't be able to use the indexes.

Comment: MySQL might get messy comparing numbers in string fields...  data_string > 20   will include the number 3 (it'll use 'alphabetical' ordering of numbers if you're not careful here... 1,11,2,20,23,3,4,5,56 etc..).  Option 2 seems safer from that aspect.

Comment: @Twelfth I just tested it and > 20 does not select the value 3. So I thing mysql casts it first

Comment: If your field only has a int in it, correct.  If you had a list with integers and numbers (it can't cast first) then it'll show 3...at least I think so anyway.